# How to verify whether a tag is present in the html code for a drop down using java in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu, tags, disabled-input

I have a disabled drop down with Values auto populated as True or False. For the auto populated value, I can see a tag named "selected" when I do the inspect element.How can I verify whether the tag "Selected" is present for the drop down?

below is the HTML part

```
<select name="text" class="Product_Selected" disabled>
<Option value="Flag_True" selected>TRUE </option>
<Option value="Flag_False">False </option> ==$0
</select>
```

As you can see above, I have selected my previous input as TRUE, so next time im getting the drop down auto populated with TRUE and is DISABLED. 
Is there any way where I can see whether tag "selected" is present for that disabled drop down using JAVA code for Selenium Webdriver

OR
Can I get the auto populated value of the Disabled Dropdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to do anything complicated... just treat it like any other `SELECT` element. There is a special class in Selenium designed to make it easier to interact with `SELECT` elements called... `Select`. I just tested this code with true and false selected and it works just fine even though the element is disabled.

```
Select e = new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("select.Product_Selected")));
System.out.println(e.getFirstSelectedOption().getText());
```

You get your `SELECT` element and send it to the `Select` constructor. Then you can interact with the `Select` element with all the new functionality. The example above just gets the selected option (first selected option in the case of a multi-select, but that doesn't apply here) and returns the text displayed, e.g. TRUE.